# Java - set data from 1 List to another

Tags: java

I have 2 lists in my program; one of the list already has data. I need to create a new List and pass few data from previous list.

Following is the code I use :

```
List<Class1> result = function();
List<Class2> newList = new ArrayList<Class2>();

for(int i=0; i < result.size(); i++) {
     newList.get(i).setValue(result.get(i).getValue());
     //setValue() is setter function in Class2
     //getValue() is getter function in Class1
    }
  return newList;
```

I get an error in this particular line when I try to run the code:

```
newList.get(i).setValue(result.get(i).getValue());
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
```

How do I resolve this issue ? Need some help with it.

Comment: You just created an empty `newList`, with no `Class2` objects in it.  What do you expect `newList.get(0)` to return exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a variable called `obj1` and `obj2`. `obj1` is an instance of some object. `obj2` is null. Then you set `obj2`'s variable to `obj1` variable. What do you get? `NullPointerException` because `obj2` is null.

To solve this problem you must create an object. For example in the `for` loop (before your `newList.get(...)` method).  You want to either copy the object or copy some variables. To do this do something like this in the `for` loop.

```
newList.set( i, result.get(i) ); // if you want to copy the class

newList.set( i, new Class2(/* ... */) );
newList.get(i).setValue( result.get(i).getValue() ); // to copy variable
```

**@Edit** you can use 1st method (newList... = result...) only if `Class2` extends `Class1`

Comment: For my case, the second method is applicable. But, I don't think that 
newList.get(i) = new Class2(/* ... */)
is going to work.

can you please suggest some way, so that I can copy a class member from 1 list to the other ? @mibac

Comment: @Arnab why do you think so? in place of `/* ... */` you just put constructor parameters.

Comment: I did try it with the constructor params. The error which it generate is for "newList.get(i)", and the error is "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

Comment: Thanks for the modified one. But, with the new code, I now get an "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" error. Any idea, why is this happening ? @mibac

Comment: any other suggestions on this issue ??